# IIS 7.5 - redirect url /index.php/* to /*

Tags: redirect, url-rewriting, iis-7.5

I have php a website set up under IIS 7 using cakePHP. It was running for quite a while using not-so-pretty urls of the form `/index.php/[controller]/[action]/[etc]`. Long enough for people to have bookmarks and Google to index everything. I've now fixed the `web.config` so that the urls that get used are of the from `/[controller]/[action]/[etc]`, bypassing the `index.php` in the url (internally it all goes to the same place).

The problem is, that if you visit one of the links in the older format, the page still technically works, but css / images / etc aren't being loaded and it looks ugly. Is there a simple way to *redirect* from the `/index.php/*` format to the new `/*` format?

The following is my existing `web.config` performing the required rewrites:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <rewrite>
            <rules>
            <rule name="Redirect static resources" stopProcessing="true">
            <match url="^(ico|img|css|files|js)(.*)$" />
            <action type="Rewrite" url="app/webroot/{R:1}{R:2}" appendQueryString="false" />
            </rule>
            <rule name="Imported Rule 1" stopProcessing="true">
            <match url="^(.*)$" ignoreCase="false" />
            <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
                        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
                        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
            </conditions>
            <action type="Rewrite" url="index.php?url={R:1}" appendQueryString="true" />
            </rule>
            <rule name="Imported Rule 2" stopProcessing="true">
            <match url="^$" ignoreCase="false" />
            <action type="Rewrite" url="/" />
            </rule>
            <rule name="Imported Rule 3" stopProcessing="true">
            <match url="(.*)" ignoreCase="false" />
            <action type="Rewrite" url="/{R:1}" />
            </rule>
            <rule name="Imported Rule 4" stopProcessing="true">
            <match url="^(.*)$" ignoreCase="false" />
            <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
                        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
                        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
            </conditions>
            <action type="Rewrite" url="index.php?url={R:1}" appendQueryString="true" />
            </rule>
            </rules>
        </rewrite>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I worked out what I was missing. In the redirect rule, I match on `/index.php/*` but I didn't realize you can add the matched string into the destination using `$0`, `$1`, `$2`, etc. Also of note, the `exactDestination="true"` is necessary, otherwise it redirected `/index.php/[controller]/[action]/[etc]` to `/[controller]/[action]/[etc]/index.php/[controller]/[action]/[etc]`

I just had to add the following section to the top of the `web.config` (in the `<system.webserver>` section, before the `<rewrite>` section:

```
<httpRedirect enabled="true" exactDestination="true" httpResponseStatus="Permanent">
  <add wildcard="/index.php/*" destination="/$0" />
</httpRedirect>
```